# Is there in python a single function that shows the full structure of a .hdf5 file?

Tags: python, hdf5

When opening a `.hdf5` file, one can explore the levels, keys and names of the file
in different ways. I wonder if there is a way or a function that displays all the available paths to explore in the `.hdf5`. Ultimately showing the whole tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `nexuformat` package to list the structure of the `hdf5` file.

Install by `pip install nexusformat`

Code

```
import nexusformat.nexus as nx
f = nx.nxload(‘myhdf5file.hdf5’)
print(f.tree)
```

This should print the entire structure of the file. For more on that see [this](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/reading-of-hdf5-structure/4479/4) thread. Examples can be found  [here](http://nexpy.github.io/nexpy/treeapi.html#module-nexusformat.nexus.tree)

Comment: I thanks! I installed the package, but whe running `nx.load('myfile.hdf5')` , I get: `Error: module 'nexusformat.nexus' has no attribute 'load' `.

It is probably `nx.nxload()`? see [here](http://nexpy.github.io/nexpy/treeapi.html#module-nexusformat.nexus.tree)

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Great, happy to help :)

Comment: gets stuck for larger files(462mb)

Comment: i doubt most library will be able to handle that size. you may need to research on how you can fragment and process this ideally.

Answer (score 8):

For all, who want to stay with the *h5py* package:

This is not a one-liner from implementation perspective, but it works with the *h5py* package. With this recursive function you can use it as one-liner:

```py
import h5py

filename_hdf = 'data.hdf5'

def h5_tree(val, pre=''):
    items = len(val)
    for key, val in val.items():
        items -= 1
        if items == 0:
            # the last item
            if type(val) == h5py._hl.group.Group:
                print(pre + '└── ' + key)
                h5_tree(val, pre+'    ')
            else:
                print(pre + '└── ' + key + ' (%d)' % len(val))
        else:
            if type(val) == h5py._hl.group.Group:
                print(pre + '├── ' + key)
                h5_tree(val, pre+'│   ')
            else:
                print(pre + '├── ' + key + ' (%d)' % len(val))

with h5py.File(filename_hdf, 'r') as hf:
    print(hf)
    h5_tree(hf)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the file schema/contents without writing any Python code or installing additional packages. If you just want to see the entire schema, take a look at the `h5dump` utility from **The HDF Group**. There are options to control the amount of detail that is dumped. Note: the default option is dump everything. To get a quick/small dump, use :`h5dump -n 1 --contents=1 h5filename.h5`.

Another Python pakcage is **PyTables**. It has a utility `ptdump` that is a command line tool to interrogate a HDF file (similar  to `h5dump` above).

Finally, here are some tips if you want to programmatically access groups and datasets recursively in Python. `h5py` and `tables` (PyTables) each have methods to do this:

**In h5py:**
Use the `object.visititems(callable)` method. It calls the callable function for each object in the tree.

**In PyTables:**
PyTables has multiple ways to recursively access groups, datasets and nodes. There are methods that return an iterable (`object.walk_nodes`), or return a list (`object.list_nodes`). There is also a method that returns an iterable that is not recursive (`object.iter_nodes`).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write the hdf5 structures into a text file. So I had to modify @Alex44's code. Now you can store the whole structure as a string in case that's what you want.

```py
import h5py

def h5_tree(val, pre='', out=""):
    length = len(val)
    for key, val in val.items():
        length -= 1
        if length == 0:  # the last item
            if type(val) == h5py._hl.group.Group:
                out += pre + '└── ' + key + "\n"
                out = h5_tree(val, pre+'    ', out)
            else:
                out += pre + '└── ' + key + f' {val.shape}\n'
        else:
            if type(val) == h5py._hl.group.Group:
                out += pre + '├── ' + key + "\n"
                out = h5_tree(val, pre+'│   ', out)
            else:
                out += pre + '├── ' + key + f' {val.shape}\n'
    return out

filename = "dummy.h5"
with h5py.File(filename, "r") as file:
    structure = h5_tree(file)
    print(structure)
```